# How to correctly use parseInt in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm doing a project in my comp sci class and my teacher wants a calculator that accepts an equation as a single string, e.g.

```
5 + 5
```

(instead of going through each variable).

My question is how do I `parseInt` correctly? It collects all the data (`int`s) before it reaches the operator. How do I tell it to collect the data past the operator?

I have tried running through the string itself until it finds a operator. And based on which operator is used it goes through my second class to calculate accordingly. But it can only collect everything before the operator. I've tried putting my string into an array and running a `for` loop backwards, but that never seemed to work.

Comment: How is the data collected? Here is the Java code?

Comment: The short answer is that you use `String.split()` to break this string up into separate elements, like the numbers and the plus sign, then you test each element to do something with it.  If the element is a number, you call `parseInt()` on it.  The longer answer is probably that you should talk with your instructor, you seem to be having a hard time, and I suspect that there's important requirements that you haven't told us.

Comment: (To be fair, when I first encountered this problem, I was a doofus and didn't talk to the instructor.  It would have been acceptable to research the problem and avoid inventing my own solution.  So yeah, talk to your instructor and make sure you have the details.)

Comment: That is my bad this is my first time on here asking questions.

Comment: The project is a multi class calculator. I have 2 classes my main class excepting inputs and my calculate class where the data is calculated. I was initially taking in inputs as three different variables. But my teacher wants to be able to insert an equation all as 1 string.  Explaining why I need to parseInt(). But doing that only except all data before reaching operator (+,-,*./) I need help getting the rest of the data in the string.

Comment: The answer below probably provides *too much* information, be careful you don't cheat/copy.  But first: does order of operations count? (What is "2 + 3 * 4?")  Do you have to deal with parenthesis?  ("(2 + 3) * 4?")

Comment: No he does not care about BEDMAS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing arithmetic, you should probably use `float` or `double` rather than `int`.

Here is a basic example of parsing a simple arithmetic expression.

```java
public class Calculate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String expression = "5 + 5";
        System.out.printf("%s = %.2f%n", expression, calculate(expression));

        try {
            calculate("33 + 5 * 2");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            calculate("33 % 2");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static double calculate(String input) {
        String[] tokens = input.trim().split("\\s+");
        if (tokens.length != 3) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input must be in the form of: <operand_1> <operator> <operand_2>");
        }
        double operand1 = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
        double operand2 = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
        String operator = tokens[1];
        switch (operator) {
            case "+":
                return operand1 + operand2;
            case "-":
                return operand1 - operand2;
            case "*":
            case "x":
                return operand1 * operand2;
            case "/":
            case "÷":
                return operand1 / operand2;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operator must be one of: +, -, *, /");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5 + 5 = 10.00
Input must be in the form of: <operand_1> <operator> <operand_2>
Operator must be one of: +, -, *, /
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... My question is how do I parseInt correctly? It collects all the data (ints) before it reaches the operator. How to I tell it to collect the data past the operator? ..."*

Use the *[Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)* and *[Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)* classes to capture the values and operators.

I'm using the following pattern.
The *look-around* asserts the `+` or  `-` are operators and not symbols.

```
(?:(?<![*/+-])[+-]|[*/])|[+-]?[^ */+-]+
```

Here is an example.

```java
import static java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP;
```

```java
String exp = "22/7";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:(?<![*/+-])[+-]|[*/])|[+-]?[^ */+-]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(exp);
List<String> a = m.results().map(MatchResult::group).toList();
Iterator<String> it = a.iterator();
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(it.next()).setScale(32, HALF_UP);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    x = switch (it.next()) {
        case "*" -> x.multiply(new BigDecimal(it.next()));
        case "/" -> x.divide(new BigDecimal(it.next()), 32, HALF_UP);
        case "+" -> x.add(new BigDecimal(it.next()));
        case "-" -> x.subtract(new BigDecimal(it.next()));
        default -> x;
    };
}
```

Output

```
3.14285714285714285714285714285714
```

As a recommendation, research the topic of the *[Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)* *data-structure*.
Essentially it is a parsing technique used to enumerate and classify values within text.
It's a common structure used with *[interpreters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing))*.

It's quite powerful, you'd be able to evaluate complex equations.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the provided equation into specific array elements I think is the way to go here as well. This is not necessarily an easy thing considering the different types of mathematical equations that can be supplied. An equation might have signed or unsigned numerical values, different type of brackets (like **( )**, **{ }**, **[ ]**), Unicode characters like PI () or even perhaps Unicode superscript exponent characters (like: ⁰, ¹, ², ³, ⁴, ⁵, ⁶, ⁷, ⁸, or ⁹). The mathematical equation might even be of an algebraic type and contain characters like "x" or "y", etc. I'm sure you're not needing to deal with such equations at this point but you may want to consider it in the future.

To evaluate a mathematical equation, it will need to be broken down into specific elements and then those elements are processed and, should be processed in **[BEDMAS](https://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/events/mathcircles/2013-14/Fall/Junior6_Oct8.pdf)** to be accurate even though it currently isn't a requirement for your current use-case.

The supplied method below will split a mathematical string equation into specific elements as discussed above and return it as a String[] array. It looks like a lot of code but, it really isn't since it is just a quick and simple parser. It's all the commenting that make it look large which you can later delete if you like. Please read the comments in code:

```
/**
 * This method will parse a math equation string, even with various bracket
 * types or nested brackets and Unicode math operators or numerical
 * characters like PI ( - Unicode: \ud835\udf45)) into a String[] Array.
 * <p>
 * Signed and unsigned integer or floating point values can be within the
 * supplied mathematical equation. Numerical values with exponents will 
 * keep their respective exponent in the parsing. 
 * <p>
 * As an example, then following equation string: "(-3.786 + 2³) * (8² / )" 
 * will be parsed as: [(, -3.786, +, 2³, ), *, 8², /, ]. 
 * <p>
 * In the above example, the superscript exponent characters ("⁰", "¹", "²", 
 * "³", "⁴", "⁵", "⁶", "⁷", "⁸", "⁹") are respective Unicode characters
 * "\u2070", "\u00B9", "\u00B2", "\u00B3", "\u2074", "\u2075", "\u2076", 
 * "\u2077", "\u2078", "\u2079". 
 * <p>
 * The character  is Unicode: \ud835\udf45.
 * <p>
 * Whitespaces are ignored during parsing and will not be contained within
 * the returned String[] Array as any kind of array element.<br>
 *
 * @param equation (String) The mathematical equation to parse into a String[] Array.<br>
 *
 * @return (String[] Array)
 */
public String[] splitSimpleEquation(String equation) {
    /* Remove all white-spacing from the supplied equation.
       We don't need them:              */
    equation = equation.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    
    /* A List Interface of String to hold all the equation elements.
       This List is later converted to a String[] array and returned. 
       We use a List because we literally have no idea how big the 
       equation might be and because of this there is no real way to 
       know how large to initialize a String[] array. A List (or an 
       ArrayList) can grow dynamically and therefore, this wouldn't 
       be a problem:     */
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // Will temporarily hold established numerical values within the equation:
    String number = ""; 
    
    /* Split the supplied equation into into a String[] array of individual
       characters so to establish proper parsing. The `equation.split("")` 
       could be used to do this but, this method WILL NOT handle two byte 
       Unicode caracters (like ) as required.        */
    String[] chr = equation.codePoints()
            .mapToObj(cp -> new String(Character.toChars(cp)))
            .toArray(size -> new String[size]);
    
    /* Iterate through the `chr` array and create the needed 
       elements to add to the List. `c` will hold the current
       string character being processed:         */
    for (String c : chr) {
        /* If the current string character is a numerical digit (0-9) or
           a decimal point (period) OR is the current string character 
           a minus character or any unicode minus character and is the 
           `number` variable empty (precursor to signed values) OR is the 
           current string character a Unicode superscript exponent character 
           and the `number` variable is NOT empty (precursor to (value to 
           the Power of) then, append the character to the contents contained 
           within the `number` variable:     */
        if (c.matches("[0-9]") || c.matches("[\\.]") || 
                (c.matches("[─➖\\-−−]") && number.isEmpty()) || 
                    (c.matches("[⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]") && !number.isEmpty())) {
            number += c;
        }
        
        /* Otherwise, if the current string character is a numerical digit
           and the `number` variable is NOT empty then, add the value 
           currently held in `number` to the List, then empty `number` in
           preparation for a new value then, add the current string 
           numerical character value to the List:            */
        else if (!c.matches("\\d") && !number.isEmpty()) {
            list.add(number);   // Add current value of `number` to the List.
            number = "";        // Empty `number` variable in prep for new value.
            list.add(c);        // Add current string numerical value to List
        }
        
        /* Otherwise, just add the current string character to the List.
           This could be a open or close bracket, a unicode PI character, 
           etc.         */
        else {
            list.add(c);
        }
    }
    
    /* Once the `chr` array has finnished iterations and there
       is still a value contained within the `number` variable 
       then, add that value to the List:        */
    if (!number.isEmpty()) {
        list.add(number);
    }
    
    // Convert the List of String to a String[] array and return it;
    return list.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

---

**Example Use #1:**

```
String[] equationElements = splitSimpleEquation("5 + 5 * 2");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(equationElements));
```

**Output Display:**

```
[5, +, 5, *, 2]
```

---

**Example Use #2:**

```
String[] equationElements = splitSimpleEquation("(-3.786 + 2³)*(8²/)*x");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(equationElements));
```

**Output Display:**

```
[(, -3.786, +, 2³, ), *, (, 8², /, , ), *, x]
```